# is there a way to set up the acl roles that are allowed to access different parts of the site in my navigation.xml?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-navigation

I have this in my bootstrap:

```
protected function _initAutoload()
{
    $this->_auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
    $this->_acl = new Federico_Plugin_Acl($this->_auth);
 ....
}
....
protected function _initNavigation()
{
    $this->bootstrap('view');

    $view = $this->getResource('view');
    $config = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/navigation.xml','nav');
    $navigation = new Zend_Navigation($config);
    $view->navigation($navigation)->setAcl($this->_acl)
                                  ->setRole($this->_auth->getStorage()->read()->role);//I just added this
}
```

however the insert I just did generated this:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_HelperAbstract::setAcl() must be an instance of Zend_Acl, instance of Federico_Plugin_Acl given, called in /home/fiodorovich/public_html/gisele/application/Bootstrap.php on line 106 and defined in /home/fiodorovich/library/ZendFramework/library/Zend/View/Helper/Navigation/HelperAbstract.php on line 333

And this is what my navigation.xml looks like so far:

```
<configdata>
<nav>
    <home>
        <label>HOME</label>
        <controller>index</controller>
        <action>index</action>
    </home>
    <about>
        <label>Nosotros</label>
        <module>default</module>
        <controller>about</controller>
        <action>index</action>
    </about>
<admin>
        <label>Admin</label>
        <uri>admin/index</uri>
        <resource>admin</resource>
        <pages>
            <alta>
                <active>0</active>
                <label>Alta Usuario</label>
                <controller>users</controller>
                <action>create</action>
            </alta>    
        </pages>
    </admin>
</nav>
```

Right now, even the guests users can see that items in the nav, althogh they can't access since that's already set up in the Acl class... how do I pass the acl roles in here?

EDIT:

```
//my acl
class Federico_Plugin_Acl extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
private $_acl = null;
private $_auth = null;
const DEFAULT_ROLE = 'guest';

public function __construct($auth)
{
    $this->_auth = $auth;

    $this->_acl = new Zend_Acl();
    $this->_acl->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role(self::DEFAULT_ROLE));
    $this->_acl->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('user'), self::DEFAULT_ROLE);
    $this->_acl->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('admin'), 'user');

    $this->_acl->addResource(new Zend_Acl_Resource('index'));
    $this->_acl->addResource(new Zend_Acl_Resource('users'));
    $this->_acl->addResource(new Zend_Acl_Resource('about'));
    $this->_acl->addResource(new Zend_Acl_Resource('gisele'));
    $this->_acl->addResource(new Zend_Acl_Resource('admin'));

    $this->_acl->allow('guest', 'index');
    $this->_acl->allow('guest', 'about');
    $this->_acl->deny('guest', 'gisele');
    $this->_acl->deny('guest', 'users');

    $this->_acl->allow('user', 'users', array('index')); 

    $this->_acl->allow('admin','users');
    $this->_acl->allow('admin','gisele');    
}

public function preDispatch (Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
{
    if ($this->_auth->hasIdentity()) {
        // user is logged in and we can get role
        $role = $this->_auth->getStorage()->read()->role;  
    } else {
        // guest
        $role = self::DEFAULT_ROLE;
    }
    $action = $request->getActionName();
    $controller = $request->getControllerName();
    if($this->_acl->has($controller)) {
        if(!$this->_acl->isAllowed($role, $controller, $action)) {
            $request->setActionName('error');
            $request->setControllerName('error');
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You can use privilege tags. Check the manual: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.navigation.pages.html

Comment: @Marcin, I understand that, but I still don't know how to pass the roles to Zend_Navigation

Comment: It's hard to follow what your current problem is. You had a question, got an answer that solved it, and then started editing/adding new things. You should have accepted that answer and posted a new question regarding the new problem(s) you encountered...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the Zend_View instance (in your bootstrap, in an action helper, wherever it's easier for you) and then:

```
$view->navigation()
    ->setAcl(Zend_Acl $acl)
    ->setRole(Zend_Acl_Role $role);
```

Basically, the navigation view helper must explicitly be given knowledge about the ACL and current role.

Comment: @faken, I just tried that and got the error message I added in the Edited version

Comment: @la_f0ka, you need to pass an instance of Zend_Acl, but you passed an instance of Federico_Plugin_Acl, which probably does not extend Zend_Acl. The Zend_Acl class is where you add all the roles and resources, it's where you add the rules (methods deny(), allow()) and where you ask if a given role is allowed to access a given resource with a given permission. That is the class you must pass to the setAcl() method in the navigation view helper.

Comment: I understand that @faken, now the problem comes when the user is not logged in. I tried with the following: 'if ($this->_auth->hasIdentity()) {
            // user is logged in and we can get role
            $view->navigation($navigation)->setRole($this->_auth->getStorage()->read()->role);
        } else {
            // guest
            $view->navigation($navigation)->setRole('guest');
        }' but I get an exception telling me that guest is not a role. I did defined that in Federico_Plugin_Acl though, which is the class where I define the roles and resources

Comment: Yes, that code you write makes sense. If you're not giving Guest permission to access admin resource, then Guest shouldn't be able to see that part of the menu. The instructions I gave you are correct, but this ACL stuff can get pretty complicated, so keep focus on which roles are authorized to access which resources. Simple test for this case: do $acl->isAllowed('guest', 'admin'), and see if it returns true or false. If guest can see the admin part of the menu, then this method will return true, and you should find out why.

Comment: Remember, even if admin part of the navigation is not visible to guests , you still need to protect these pages, for example making a $acl->isAllowed in the preDispatch() method in the pages you want to protect (if not allowed, redirect to login, to whatever makes sense to you).

Comment: what's bugging me is the 'Zend_Acl_Role_Registry_Exception: Role 'guest' not found in /home/fiodorovich/library/ZendFramework/library/Zend/View/Helper/Navigation/HelperAbstract.php on line 522' . how can I pass the guest user if not like I did?

Comment: You have to setup Zend_Acl with all possible roles that will come into play, including guest, before you ask any isAllowed questions. For example, you you want to deny access to all protected resources to guest, you should: 1 - add a guest role, e.g. $acl->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('guest')); 2 - deny all protected access to guest, e.g. $acl->deny('guest') (although guest is denied everything by default its always good to be explicit). I suggest you read the Zend_Acl docs carefully, as they explain this in detail: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.html

Comment: PS - When rendering the menu, the navigation view helper asks the "isAllowed" question for you; that's why it needs the ACL and role objects to begin with.

Comment: @faken, I've read and implemented the acl and roles as you can see in the class I just added to the thread. That's why it's so weird that this keeps telling me that the roles aren't defined

Comment: Well, my last advice is: do a lot of explicit tests with isAllowed, to check what roles and resources are in fact loaded, and if the rules are giving the correct result. When you have 100% that is working, jump to the navigation access. Anyway, for the ACL navigation part take a look at http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.navigation.acl , which is a detailed explanation of my answer to you original question. Good luck!